# How to add a line break before each set of CJK characters ([\o200-\o377]) with sed?

Tags: bash, sed, cjk

I have a document containing a mixture of Chinese and English text, e.g.:

```
This is some text.你好。This is some more text.
```

I need to place a line break only before each portion of Chinese text, or `[\o200-\o377]`. E.g.:

```
This is some text.
你好。This is some more text.
```

I tried this, but it is putting each of the Chinese characters on unique lines:

```
LC_ALL="POSIX" sed 's/[\o200-\o377]/\n&/g'
```

How can I add a line break before each CJK character with `sed`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're actually replacing *every instance* of such a character with a newline and what was matched. you appear to want to replace every *sequence of at least one* such character, with a newline followed by what was matched.

```
s/[\o200-\o377]\+/\n&/g
```

(note: `sed` probably expects approximately posix regex—mine claims "POSIX.2  BREs  should  be supported, but they aren't completely because of performance problems." Thus, `\+` is correct. using "extended" (`sed -r`), simply `+`, thus `s/[\o200-\o377]+/\n&/g`, would be correct.)